# Can the different types of a correlation coefficients be generalized under one definition?

Tags: correlation, association-measure

I am writing to ask "can the concept of a correlation coefficient be generalized, such that all the types of correlation coefficients commonly used (pearson, spearman's etc) are specific cases of it." Or, alternatively, can certain correlation coefficients be generalized if others are not included? If so, which and why?

I have no idea whether this is a "good question" or not. As a result, I am not sure if answering the above will be fruitful. In case it is not, I would like to ask if there are other concepts that might help me (with the below). For example, maybe generalization of CC is not sensical, but instead you recommend I look into information entropy or something else.

The reason I am asking is because of my work in genetics. People have used Pearson's r for a long time, but our understanding of genetic variation is changing as technology grows. Specifically, in the future I think we will need a more flexible definition, that is capable of accurately describing a variety of types of genetic variation.

Comment: These are all measures of association.

Comment: thanks for your reply - i meant generalization in mathematical terms, and ideally the definition would not include other disparate statistics, e.g. a Z-statistic, which does relate to association but is not a metric for correlation.

Comment: Related:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534454/a-formal-definition-of-a-measure-of-association/535771#535771